# Compute binomial coefficient module prime p in C++

Tags: c++, primes, modulo

Problem statement: Compute the binonimal coefficient C(n,k) mod p. Here p is a prime.
I've done a bit of research online but I still don't understand why the following code works for this problem:

```cpp
factorial[0] = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= MAXN; i++) {//compute factorial
    factorial[i] = factorial[i - 1] * i % m;
}
long long binomial_coefficient(int n, int k) {
    return factorial[n] * inverse(factorial[k] * factorial[n - k] % m) % m;//I don't get it why we have to multiply with inverse(factorial[k] * factorial[n - k] % m)
}
```

I know the definition of modular inverse but i'm still confused how it can be relevant here. Can someone help me clarify this code ?

Comment: The other thing that's relevant here is that `p` is prime, which is the (necessary and sufficient) condition for the modular inverse to exist and be unique for all values not `≡ 0 mod p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorial [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) `C(n, k) = n! / (k! (n-k)!)` can be rewritten as `C(n, k) k! (n-k)! = n!`. Then:

- taking `mod p` on both sides:  `C(n, k) k! (n-k)! ≡ n! mod p`;
- multiplying by the modular inverse:  `C(n, k) k! (n-k)! inverse(k! (n-k)!) ≡ n! inverse(k! (n-k)!) mod p`;
- simplifying `a inv(a) = 1`:  `C(n, k) ≡ n! inverse(k! (n-k)!) mod p`.

The latter is equivalent to `C(n, k) mod p = ((n! mod p) (inverse(k! (n-k)!) mod p)) mod p`.

Comment: if `n` > `p` then the denominator will be 0 mod p and thus not invertible. However, C(n,k) = 0 mod p for n>=p so that can just be a special case.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Right. Also, `n! mod p = 0` when `n >= p` so the formula will still hold (at least assuming `inverse` does not `throw`).